# T-SQL: Insert in table results of CTE

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, insert, common-table-expression

I have this TSQL syntax :

```
WITH cte AS(
SELECT Stamps, row_number() over (order by (SELECT 1)) rn from week
unpivot      
(Stamps FOR Day IN ([Sun], [Mon], [Tue], [Wed], [Thu], [Fri], [Sat]) ) AS unpvt )

SELECT Stamps + ': ' +STUFF((SELECT ','+cast(rn as varchar(9)) from cte where Stamps=A.TimeStamps FOR XML PATH('')), 1 , 1 , '' ) from cte A group by Stamps
```

This give me for each "Stamps" the number of the day.
For example if the Table is :

`S2 | S0 | S0 | S1 | S1 | S3 | S2`

The result will be:

```
S0 : 2,3
S1 : 4,5
S2 : 1,7
S3 : 6
```

This part works well, but now I would like to put this result in a table

Like `Insert Into mytable (S0, S1, S2, S3) = ('2,3','4,5','1,7','6')`

But when I do Set after or before it doesn't work.
How can I do it?
Thanks

Comment: You shouldn't be storing comma separated values - they're awkward to work with, make writing general queries difficult, etc. And it looks like you've embedded data in your column names with `S0` - `S3`, if they're all actually representing the same "type" of data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to pivot it back.  How about this:

```
WITH cte AS(
SELECT Stamps, row_number() over (order by (SELECT 1)) rn from week
unpivot      
(Stamps FOR Day IN ([Sun], [Mon], [Tue], [Wed], [Thu], [Fri], [Sat]) ) AS unpvt 
), cte2 AS (

SELECT Stamps , STUFF((SELECT ','+cast(rn as varchar(9)) 
                             from cte where Stamps=A.[Stamps] FOR XML PATH('')), 1 , 1 , '' ) 
  as DayList
from cte A
group by Stamps
)
INSERT MyTable (S0, S1, S2, S3)
select S0, S1, S2, S3 from cte2
PIVOT
(
Max(DayList)
FOR Stamps IN ([S0], [S1], [S2], [S3])
) AS PivotTable;
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/37ff8/2

Comment: it works but if I insert others values like 00, 02. the result will be null. So far I didn't find why. do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Insert other values where?  I don't really understand what these "Stamps" are or what you're trying to accomplish.